# Refreshing Custom Ribbon Tab in Excel 2010 When Someone Clicks on the Tab

Tags: vsto, excel-2010, ribbonx

I've been writing a custom ribbon with VSTO (using VB.net and XML) and I have written a number of buttons who's labels & pressed states depend on the calculation mode that Excel is in.

The getPressed and getLabels callback functions check for the excel calculation mode but these are only called when the ribbon is first loaded or the buttons are clicked. If someone were to go into the "formulas" tab, change the calculation mode and then go back to the custom ribbon tab, the pressed states and labels on the buttons in this custom tab would now be incorrect.

Is there a way to trigger these callback functions to be called (eg a way to call the ribbon.invalidate() function) when someone clicks on the custom ribbon tab in Excel?